# Was one of Uyyakondar's shishyas a relative of Nathamuni?

Tags: history, temple, practice, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

The Alwars (also spelled Azhwars) are a group of 12 ancient Vaishnava saints who lived in Tamil Nadu and are famous for their poetry in praise of Vishnu. The 4000 verses of the Alwars were compiled by the Vaishnava Acharya Nathamuni into a book called the Naalayira Divya Prabhandam, which is considered by many to be the "Dravida Veda", or South Indian Veda. It's the principles and beliefs embodied in the Alwars' poems that Nathamuni used to found what we now call the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I am a member).

Now Nathamuni's chief disciple was Uyyakondar, also known as Pundarikaksha.  Uyyakondar's shishyas are listed in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/DViX) from Vedanta Desikan's Rahasyatraya Sara:

> Uyyakondar had five disciples; they are: - Manakkal Nambi, **Thiruvallikeni Pan Perumal Araiyar**, Settalur Sendalangarar, Sri Pundarika Dasar, and Ulagaperumal Nangai.

Manakkal Nambi was Uyyakondar's chief disciple, but I'm interested in the second name, "Thiruvallikeni Pan Perumal Araiyar". Thiruvallikeni is the ancient name for Triplicane, the site of the Parthasarathi Vishnu temple which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22754/36). And Araiyar refers to Araiyar Seva, a practice introduced by Nathamuni where the Alwars' poems are set to song and dance.  So that means this shishya of Uyyakondar was the one performing Araiyar Seva in the Parthasarathi temple.  Nowadays Araiyar Seva is only done in Sri Rangam and a few other temples, but [this webpage](https://arayasamajam.blogspot.in/2013/07/arayar-sevai_7.html) indicates that in the olden days many temples including the Parthasarathi temple used to do it.

Now at least in the Sri Rangam temple, the Araiyars (people who do Araiyar Seva) are all from Nathamuni's family.  So my question is, was Thiruvallikeni Pan Perumal Araiyar a relative of Nathamuni? Or were the Araiyars of the Parthasarathi temple not related to Nathamuni?

By the way, regardless of the answer, Uyyakondar's shishya Manakkal Nambi at least had one of Nathamuni's relatives as a shishya, namely Nathamuni's grandson Yamunacharya,

Comment: Dravida Veda????

Comment: Yes, you've never heard that phrase before?